# Is there anything omitted before sufficient?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, ellipsis, subjects

> We should be less concerned with students' 'cognitive impatience', however, than by what may underlie it: the potential inability of large numbers of students to read with a level of critical analysis **sufficient** to comprehend the complexity of thought and argument found in more demanding texts.

I want to know if there is anything omitted before the word sufficient? For instance, *that is* or *which is*? If so, is it an adjective clause?

I think this way of writing is quite common but I just realised that I don't understand what it is "technically."

Apart from that, I would appreciate if someone can help me identify the *subject*, *object* and all the other elements in this sentence since it's a terrible long one for me, I did spend some time reading it.

Comment: I think that your sentence is an example of whiz-deletion: the question that I referred to provides a good explanation of how this works, when it's allowed, etc. Regarding subject, object, etc, I recommend dividing the sentence up into several clauses, then looking for parts of speech in the clauses.